# How to attach click listener to a dynamically created child element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that similar questions are being asked (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280569/jquery-select-dynamically-created-html-element)) but, being a jQuery noob,  I still can not attach a click listener to an `a` element within a `li` where the whole `ul.li.a` is dynamically appended to the DOM like this.

```
<div id="users-col">
  <!-- dynamically appended --> 
  <ul id="users-list">
       <li>
          <a class="user" id="Alice">Alice</a>
       </li>
       <li>
          <a class="user" id="Bob">Bob</a>
       </li>
  </ul>
   <!-- END dynamically appended --> 
</div>
```

Here is a (one of the many) jQuery functions that I have tried:

```
$('#users-col ul.li.a').on('click', '.user', (function () {
  console.log('user clicked:', this.id); 
});
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `li` and `a` are not classes, so they shouldn't have `.` in front of them if you're trying to select them. Separate elements with `>` to indicate parent - child relationship.

Comment: Well, I also tried `$("#users-col ul > li > a")` but failed.

Comment: @Karlom `$("#users-col ul > li > a")` will not work since your `ul` `li` and `a` are dynamically created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind the event on element that is available (not added dynamically)

```
$('#users-col').on('click', 'a.user', (function () {
  console.log('user clicked:', this.id); 
});
```

For reference, [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

in such case you must hook an event with parent of dynamically created children:

```
$('#users-col').on('click', 'a.user',        (function () { 
console.log('click bound'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For convenience sake and reuse, I leave the first field just directly tied to the document:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.user', (function () {
  console.log('user clicked:', this.id);
}));
```

```html
<div id="users-col">
    <!-- dynamically appended -->
    <ul id="users-list">
        <li>
            <a class="user" id="Alice">Alice</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="user" id="Bob">Bob</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- END dynamically appended -->
</div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
```

The listener is directly tied to the document vice the class, so now it is very easy to reuse this class dynamically across your entire document.

Comment: I had try this. Its problem was that it was triggered for whatever click on the page.

Comment: @Karlom no, it should only trigger for tags with class="user".
Unless your body contains class user, it shouldn't trigger for every click.