# Hiding element codes when debugging on chrome?

Tags: javascript

The code I'm debugging in action is here:

https://reed123.000webhostapp.com/test/story_html5.html

If I hover my mouse over the pin of the dial I got aria-label for the pin like this:

[image]

But when I move the mouse out of the pin the aria-label of the pin hides:

[image]

The bad news is I can't select the pin with its aria-label using jQuery.

I've tried :

```
var item = $('[aria-label="spinner Dial 1 range from 0 to 12"]')
$(item).animate({'top': '-=30px'},'slow');
```

But it seems that I can't select the pin using this aria-label!!!

Please help, I really need that aria-label to select the pin using jQuery.

**Why I can't have that aria-label and how to select it?**

Comment: I see the website just fine...with persistent `aria-label`

Comment: The element has a class, why not hook onto that?

Comment: Which one let me know, please...

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to select dynamically created element. Look here - [jQuery select dynamically created html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280569/jquery-select-dynamically-created-html-element)