# on-click handler for when element doesnt exist in the dom yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

https://www.flashfeed.io/app/showcase

I'm trying to make a click of the "video" or "photo" applied filter tag also click the element which has "view all". Similar how the reset button current works.

[image]

```js
// reset contenttype on video or photo genre
const appliedFilterTag = document.querySelectorAll('[fs-cmsfilter-element="tag-remove"]');

appliedFilterTag.forEach(element => {
  const innerText = element.innerText.toLowerCase();

  if (innerText === "video" || innerText === "photo") {
    element.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const allFilterElement = document.querySelector('#all-filter');
      allFilterElement.click();
    });
  }
});
```

This code works, but only when the applied filter element is currently existing in the DOM. I tried to just make an onclick function of the an element with the tag [fs-cmsfilter-element="tag-remove"] so that it logically would only run whenever the tag exists, but it just isnt working. Cant figure it out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery select dynamically created html element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280569/jquery-select-dynamically-created-html-element)

Comment: Also, you tagged jQuery but don't use it at all.

Comment: Sounds like you need *event delegtion*

Answer (score 0):

Use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). Here's a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  `beforeend`, 
  `<button id="click1">button 1</button>
   <br><button id="click2">button 2</button>`);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `click1`) {
    console.clear();
    return console.log(`You clicked button 1`);
  }
  
  if (evt.target.id === `click2`) {
    console.clear();
    return console.log(`You clicked button 2`);
  }
  
  // Not existing (yet), but no problem now
  if (evt.target.id === `click3`) {
    console.clear();
    return console.log(`You clicked button 3`);
  }
}
```

```css
button {margin-bottom: 0.2rem;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function resetContentTypeFilter() {
    const innerText = this.innerText.toLowerCase();

    if (innerText === "video" || innerText === "photo") {
        const allFilterElement = document.querySelector('#all-filter');
        allFilterElement.click();
    }
}

const appliedFilterTag = document.querySelector('[fs-cmsfilter-element="tag-remove"]');
if (appliedFilterTag) {
    appliedFilterTag.addEventListener('click', resetContentTypeFilter);
}
```

The 'appliedFilterTag' is selected using querySelector() instead of querySelectorAll() which will returns a single element.

The if condition checks whether 'appliedFilterTag' element exists in DOM, and if it does the event listener is added.

Now, only when the 'appliedFilterTag' is clicked 'resetContentTypeFilter' is executed.